# a question about tensorflow tutorial "model()" vs "model.predict()"

Tags: tensorflow

why i change "predictions = model(input_eval)" to "predictions = model.predict(input_eval)" it got an error:

> CancelledError:  [Op:StatefulPartitionedCall]

here are codes

```
def generate_text(model, start_string):
  # Evaluation step (generating text using the learned model)

  # Number of characters to generate
  num_generate = 1000

  # Converting our start string to numbers (vectorizing) 
  input_eval = [char2idx[s] for s in start_string]
  input_eval = tf.expand_dims(input_eval, 0)

  # Empty string to store our results
  text_generated = []

  # Low temperatures results in more predictable text.
  # Higher temperatures results in more surprising text.
  # Experiment to find the best setting.
  temperature = 1.0

  # Here batch size == 1
  model.reset_states()
  for i in range(num_generate):
      predictions = model(input_eval)
      # remove the batch dimension
      predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)

      # using a multinomial distribution to predict the word returned by the model
      predictions = predictions / temperature
      predicted_id = tf.multinomial(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()

      # We pass the predicted word as the next input to the model
      # along with the previous hidden state
      input_eval = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)

      text_generated.append(idx2char[predicted_id])

  return (start_string + ''.join(text_generated))
```

link:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hoEHMCQrZYFJnNoWzRNTmPjQUFrPvTWy

Comment: `model ( input_val )` is only called when an object of type `keras.models.Model` is called on another object of the same type in order to stack them up ( Just as we call layers on each other ). Hence `input_val` must be a `keras.models.Model`  object. To predict one should use `model.predict()` method.

Comment: the tutorial demo uses `model(input_val)`，you  can click here[link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/sequences/text_generation.ipynb#scrollTo=AM2Uma_-yVIq),this code can run successfully,i don't know why they use `model(input_val)` instead of `model.predict(input_val)`...

Comment: it's a bug,when i install `tensorflow-nightly`, there is no error...